# PL/SQL Increase value of new row, with value of previous

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to increase value of next `NEWLOSAL` row, to be bigger than one, from previous of `NEWHISA`.
Like `HISAL` and `LOSAL` column.
`NEWLOSAL` need to be previous `NEWHISAL + 1`.

[image]

Comment: When do you need to increase, On insert? Or do you want to update the entire table at once?

Comment: I need to update table,

Comment: UPDATE SALGRADE
  SET
  NEWHISAL = hisal + hisal * GRADE * 10/100;

This is how I increase NEWHISAL.

Comment: The "previous" row only exists if you can order the rows by something. So based on which `order by` criteria do you determine the "previous" row? I also removed the `plsql` as this question doesn't seem to require a stored procedure for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not that sure if this is what you want:

```
  update table1 t1 
    set t1.Newlosal=case when t1.grade=1 then (t1.Newhisal+1) else (select t2.Newhisal+1 from table1 t2 where t2.grade = (t1.grade-1)) end
    WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
  FROM table1 t2
 WHERE t2.grade=(t1.grade-1))
```

Comment: @Richard.McConory cause you didn't tell us how to deal with the first row my man, i just edited to add a case when in the update for first row i set it to himself's Newhisal+1

Comment: I update first row, before this query, and it work :)
Thanks.

Comment: @Richard.McConory glad to help, if you could accept the answer would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

This can efficiently be done using the `merge` statement and a window function:

```
merge into table1 tg
using
(
   select id, -- I assume this is the PK column
          lag(newhisal) over (order by grade) + 1 as new_losal
   from table1
) nv on (nv.id = tg.id)
when matched then update 
   set tg.newlosal = nv.new_losal;
```

In SQL rows in a table (or a result) or not ordered, so the concept of a "previous" row **only** makes sense if you define a sort order. That's what the `over (order by grade)` does in the window function. From the screen shot I can not tell by which column this should be sorted.

The screen shot also doesn't reveal the primary key column of your table. I assumed it's named `ID`. You have to change that to reflect your real PK column name.

I also didn't include a `partition by` clause in the window function assuming that the formula should be applied for all rows in the same way. If this is not the case you need to be more specific with your sample data.